# Removing a USB external disk without properly ejecting it

Tags: usb, data-integrity

What are the integrity-related issues I might have by simply removing a USB external hard disk from my computer, without logically disconnecting it (e.g. via Windows desktop bar icon)?

Is the concern only related to possible data lost which is currently being processed or you can actually physically damage the device?

Comment: i have a dead USB memory stick that resulted from doing this.  if it is updating the internal block pool when power is cut, cheaper devices can corrupt their internal info.

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to always eject the USB disk properly. In certain (rare) scenarios, data can become corrupted if you just yank it out. One reason for this is that the OS's write cache may not have been flushed completely. See [Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5863810/do-i-really-need-to-eject-usb-drives-before-removing-them).

The risk of physical damage is not significant, unless you have a SSD drive.

Comment: in Linux a `umount` operation will sync the device, flushing buffers